# Looking for the right word in this sentence. "He found the right environment at the academy to ____ his interest in art."

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a few possibilities but I'm looking for a better word to describe how the person was helped by the environment in his pursuit of art.

He found the right environment at the academy to work on his interest in art.

He found the right environment at the academy to promote his interest in art.

He found the right environment at the academy to advance his interest in art.

**hone** doesn't seem to go here:
He found the right environment at the academy to *hone* his interest in art.

Comment: consider "encourage" or "stimulate".

Comment: *Pique* can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider ***[cultivate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cultivate)***:

> 2a :  to foster the growth of
>   2c :  to improve by labor, care, or study
>   *<sub>from [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cultivate)</sub>*

He found the right environment at the academy to *cultivate* his interest in art.

Comment: Yes cultivate was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the more literal defintion of [kindle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kindle), to ignite or set on fire, is a slightly figurative one, to stir up or excite.

In your examples, this becomes:

> He found the right environment at the academy to kindle his interest in art.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "interest" is not the thing that can be "promoted" or "advanced" by the environment. But, the environment can be a factor for a person persuading him to follow his or her interests. So, I think it is better to say:

> to pursue his interest

or

> to follow his interest

or

> to focus on his interest

Comment: I think you are right.  "Pursue" was the word I immediately thought of.  Can you add a definition of pursue?  If you do, send me a message and I will upvote.